# More elegant way to ignore static urls in Middleware in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

Middleware-Wizards,

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to find out whether a request serves one of my custom view methods or rather static content etc. instead?

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if view_func.__name__ != 'serve':
            # do something here
        return None
```

Comment: I'm curious what you're trying to do - `serve()` isn't meant to be used in production, so I don't see why this middleware would be useful.

Comment: Ah that's true! I forgot about that :) What I basically want to achieve is to create a log entry for every page that is visited in order to better understand how people use the website and improve the website based on the results :)

Comment: I think it'll be better to use some javascript for it, so you won't slow down all requests.

Comment: @beezz: interesting, I'll give that a try as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are serving static files only via [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-url) you can check `request.path`. ([process_request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process_request))

```
def process_request(request):
    if request.path.startswith(settings.STATIC_URL):
        # do something here
```

Anyway that's applicable only during development cause usually apache or nginx or some CDN is serving static files and those requests will never hit your django app.